# Routing audio to Bluetooth Headset (non-A2DP) on Android

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I have a non-A2DP single ear BT headset (Plantronics 510) and would like to use it with my Android HTC Magic to listen to low quality audio like podcasts/audio books.

After much googling I found that only phone call audio can be routed to the non-A2DP BT headsets. (I would like to know if you have found a ready solution to route all kinds of audio to non-A2DP BT headsets)

So I figured, somehow programmatically I can channel the audio to the stream that carries phone call audio. This way I will fool the phone to carry my mp3 audio to my BT headset. I wrote following simple code.

```
import android.content.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.*;
import java.io.*;
import android.util.Log;

public class BTAudioActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = "BTAudioActivity";

    private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
    private AudioManager amanager = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        amanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        amanager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
        amanager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(new FileInputStream(
                "/sdcard/sample.mp3").getFD());

            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);

            mPlayer.prepare();

            mPlayer.start();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        mPlayer.stop();
        amanager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
        amanager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried combinations of various methods that I thought will fool the phone to believe my audio is a phone call:

- Using MediaPlayer's setAudioStreamType(STREAM_VOICE_CALL)
- using AudioManager's setBluetoothScoOn(true)
- using AudioManager's setMode(MODE_IN_CALL)

But none of the above worked. If I remove the AudioManager calls in the above code, the audio plays from speaker and if I replace them as shown above then the audio stops coming from speakers, but it doesn't come through the BT headset. So this might be a partial success.

I have checked that the BT headset works alright with phone calls.

There must be a reason for Android not supporting this. But I can't let go of the feeling that it is not possible to programmatically reroute the audio. Any ideas?

P.S. above code needs following permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>`

Comment: You may not need to write any code yourself.  Simply install a free app which is designed to do what you want.  See the Android.SE question: ["Is it possible to direct all audio output, including music output, to a Bluetooth headset?"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19336/is-it-possible-to-direct-all-audio-output-to-a-bluetooth-headset)  I tried a few different apps.  In the end, "Mono Bluetooth Router" was the only one which worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

This thread may be long dead but for those who might be trying the same thing, some notes from the AudioManager docs may be useful. It looks like the missing element is the startBluetoothSco() command but there are restrictions on the use of this channel. From the Android Dev site [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#startBluetoothSco()):

> > public void startBluetoothSco ()  Since: API Level 8 Start bluetooth SCO
> >     audio connection.
>
> Requires Permission:
>   MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS.
>
> This method can be used by
>   applications wanting to send and
>   received audio to/from a bluetooth SCO
>   headset while the phone is not in
>   call.
>
> As the SCO connection establishment
>   can take several seconds, applications
>   should not rely on the connection to
>   be available when the method returns
>   but instead register to receive the
>   intent ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
>   and wait for the state to be
>   SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED.
>
> As the connection is not guaranteed to
>   succeed, applications must wait for
>   this intent with a timeout.
>
> When finished with the SCO connection
>   or if the establishment times out, the
>   application must call
>   stopBluetoothSco() to clear the
>   request and turn down the bluetooth
>   connection.
>
> **Even if a SCO connection is
>   established, the following
>   restrictions apply on audio output
>   streams so that they can be routed to
>   SCO headset: - the stream type must be
>   STREAM_VOICE_CALL - the format must be
>   mono - the sampling must be 16kHz or
>   8kHz**
>
> The following restrictions apply on
>   input streams: - the format must be
>   mono - the sampling must be 8kHz
>
> Note that the phone application always
>   has the priority on the usage of the
>   SCO connection for telephony. If this
>   method is called while the phone is in
>   call it will be ignored. Similarly, if
>   a call is received or sent while an
>   application is using the SCO
>   connection, the connection will be
>   lost for the application and NOT
>   returned automatically when the call
>   ends.
>
> See Also stopBluetoothSco()
>   ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED

Note that I have not tested this, I'm just passing along a lead I found in researching a similar project. I think Jayesh was close to the solution and the restrictions above may have been what was keeping it from working.

Comment: startBluetoothSco() and  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>

Comment: I have added this STREAM_VOICE_CALL but in some of samsung device(Samsung S6) it works and on other it wont work. Is their any other mode to record voice from bluetooth mode for all devices. I have also tried  with MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION .

Answer (score 10):

To turn on:

```
 localAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 localAudioManager.setMode(0);
 localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
 localAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
 localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

To turn off:

```
 localAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
 localAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
 localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
```

[I took it from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295698/verify-connected-bluetooth-headsets-on-android)

Comment: What is the difference between ```setBluetoothScoOn(true)``` and ```startBluetoothSco()```?

Answer (score 3):

Great Work it is working fine for me please do bit modification in your code it'll work perfectly i.e.

```
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL); 

to 

mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be a ALSA route path configured for Media player, so that it can open a different audio path and then route your audio to BT headset.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot see a clear accepted working application so putting a new answer. This application routes music and audio to Non A2dp headsets. Try my application and find the source code also in github for reference code. https://github.com/sauravpradhan/AnySound2BT