# How to Verify whether bluetooth headsets are connected on Android?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, headset

How to verify if there is any bluetooth headsets conected to android at the moment?

Like:

- If there is a headset conected, the sound must route to this headset
- But if there isnt a headset, the sound must stay on speaker
- This must check during the application because if the battery of the headset goes off it must send sound to speaker back

Solution below /

```
public class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private AudioManager localAudioManager;
    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED  = 0x00000000;
    private static final String EXTRA_STATE = "android.bluetooth.headset.extra.STATE";
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothReceiver";
    private static final String ACTION_BT_HEADSET_STATE_CHANGED  = "android.bluetooth.headset.action.STATE_CHANGED";
    private static final String ACTION_BT_HEADSET_FORCE_ON = "android.bluetooth.headset.action.FORCE_ON";
    private static final String ACTION_BT_HEADSET_FORCE_OFF = "android.bluetooth.headset.action.FORCE_OFF";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onReceive - BluetoothBroadcast");
        localAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(ACTION_BT_HEADSET_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int extraData = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_STATE, STATE_DISCONNECTED);
            if (extraData == STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
                localAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
                localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
                Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth Headset Off " + localAudioManager.getMode());
                Log.i(TAG, "A2DP: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn() + ". SCO: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall());
            } else {            
                localAudioManager.setMode(0);
                localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
                localAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
                localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth Headset On " + localAudioManager.getMode());
                Log.i(TAG, "A2DP: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn() + ". SCO: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall());
            }
        }   

        if (action.equals(ACTION_BT_HEADSET_FORCE_ON)) {
            localAudioManager.setMode(0);
            localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
            localAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
            localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
            Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth Headset On " + localAudioManager.getMode());
            Log.i(TAG, "A2DP: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn() + ". SCO: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall());
        }

        if (action.equals(ACTION_BT_HEADSET_FORCE_OFF)) {
            localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
            localAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
            localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
            Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth Headset Off " + localAudioManager.getMode());
            Log.i(TAG, "A2DP: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn() + ". SCO: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just cleaned your code and generalized it a bit for other users having the same problem. Don't post unrelated stuff like "android.bluetooth.headset.action.FORCE_ON" or "android.bluetooth.headset.action.FORCE_OFF" (which refer to your self-created actions). Also don't use foreign language comments, please. :) Btw, thank you for the code. :)

Comment: Best and most complete solution I found!

Answer (score 2):

Moving this to an answer so that further comments can made. Works great!

```
public class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private AudioManager localAudioManager;
    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED  = 0x00000000;
    private static final String EXTRA_STATE = "android.bluetooth.headset.extra.STATE";
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothReceiver";
    private static final String ACTION_BT_HEADSET_STATE_CHANGED  = "android.bluetooth.headset.action.STATE_CHANGED";
    private static final String ACTION_BT_HEADSET_FORCE_ON = "android.bluetooth.headset.action.FORCE_ON";
    private static final String ACTION_BT_HEADSET_FORCE_OFF = "android.bluetooth.headset.action.FORCE_OFF";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onReceive - BluetoothBroadcast");
        localAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(ACTION_BT_HEADSET_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int extraData = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_STATE, STATE_DISCONNECTED);
            if (extraData == STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
                localAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
                localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
                Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth Headset Off " + localAudioManager.getMode());
                Log.i(TAG, "A2DP: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn() + ". SCO: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall());
            } else {            
                localAudioManager.setMode(0);
                localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
                localAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
                localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth Headset On " + localAudioManager.getMode());
                Log.i(TAG, "A2DP: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn() + ". SCO: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall());
            }
        }   

        if (action.equals(ACTION_BT_HEADSET_FORCE_ON)) {
            localAudioManager.setMode(0);
            localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
            localAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
            localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
            Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth Headset On " + localAudioManager.getMode());
            Log.i(TAG, "A2DP: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn() + ". SCO: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall());
        }

        if (action.equals(ACTION_BT_HEADSET_FORCE_OFF)) {
            localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
            localAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
            localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
            Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth Headset Off " + localAudioManager.getMode());
            Log.i(TAG, "A2DP: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn() + ". SCO: " + localAudioManager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall());
        }
    }
}
```