# How to: force output sound of application to go through Bluetooth headset

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth headset (coupled with my smartphone) which produces sound of dial signal while waiting for connection and your interlocutor during conversation.

All other sounds like: keypress sound, mp3, other sounds of different applications is generated by the speaker of the smartphone.

My question:
Is there any possible way, to write an application in AS 3.0 which will force the sound of this application to go through bluetooth headset (but not through a smartphone speaker)?
I know that it may be connected with something called "system sound", but all my reaserch come to naught.

Comment: I haven't heard of anything similar in "plain AS3", so if such a feature exists, it would need to be AIR-specific, which means the application needs to be "installable" and not a web app.

Answer (score 1):

First solution: install [BTmono](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bedoig.BTmono)
this 4rd party allows you to send sound from app to headset.
Second: Use [Native Extensions,](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) write it in the Android SDK. On this, you'll find lots of helps on the Internet, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144694/routing-audio-to-bluetooth-headset-non-a2dp-on-android). This will be a lot of work, requiring both AS and Java knowledge. Also don't forget to mark BT Headset in permissions.